# regular expression for mongoose not passing not passing from Angular's HTTP service to nodejs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am trying to create a mongoose query on client side, I am creating a regular expression for case insensitive queries like below

```
query = {city: {'$regex': /NY/i}}
```

However when I am getting the data on server I am getting an empty object like below

```
query = {city: {'$regex': {}}}
```

I am not sure what am I doing wrong.

My angular service function for passing the data looks like below.

```
queryDB: function(query) {
                    var deferred = $q.defer();
                    $http.post("/path", {data: query})
                            .success(function(response) {
                                deferred.resolve(response);
                            })
                            .error(function(error) {
                                deferred.reject(error);
                            })

                    return deferred.promise;
                },
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to pass a javascript object generated on the browser side to the express server. The data specified in the $http service calls transform the data from javascript objects to JSON. JSON is a way to represent data in text form so when your regexp is transformed to an emptry object. To verify this, simply execute the statements in node.js shell.

```
> query = {city: {'$regex': /NY/i}}
{ city: { '$regex': /NY/i } }
> console.log(JSON.stringify(query))
{"city":{"$regex":{}}}
```

To get your required result, you should send in your data in text form and then generate a regular expression on the server side and then execute the regular expression query using mongoose.You can use a flag to check if the query is supposed to be a regular expression or plain text search.

```
var query = {city: {data: "NY", isRegex: true}}
```

And then on the server side you create a regexp object based on the flag

```
var regex = new regExp(city.data, 'i')
```

You should also escape your regular expression as it is being generated from user input. Use a regular expression escape function which would escape all the special characters in regexp.

```
function escapeRegExp(str) {
  return str.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&");
}
```